# Paralax Effect css

Tags: html, css, 3d

Проблема такая:

1. Есть шаблон паралакса который я хочу "прикрепить" к своему проекту. [Вот ссылка на этот эффект](https://codepen.io/ksksoft/pen/OPKQBP).
2. Есть ли возможность сделать так что бы моя картинка которая на backgraund стоит оставалась в HTML а не в CSS.

   [мой код](https://codepen.io/ksksoft/pen/OPKQBP)

```css
html {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    body {
      color: #fff;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
     -webkit-perspective: 1px;
     perspective: 1px;
     -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    header {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      min-height: 40vw;
      padding: 30vw 0 5vw;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform-style: inherit;
      transform-style: inherit;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    header, header:before {
      background: 50% 50% / cover;
    }
    header::before {
      bottom: 0;
      content: "";
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
     display: block;
     background-color: #8a8;
      background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70180925/dimg/orengeFlower.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      -webkit-transform-origin: center center 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
      transform-origin: center center 0;
      transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
      z-index: -1;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
    header * {
      font-weight: normal;
      letter-spacing: 0.2em;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
     padding: 1em 0;
    }
    header p {
      background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%,0.1);
    }
    main {
      background-color: hsl(60, 10%, 10%);
      line-height: 1.7;
      max-width: 32em;
      padding: 5% calc(50% - 16em) 35%;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

```html
<header>
      <h1>Parallax header</h1>
      <p>Parallax scroll effect like Twitter. Pure css, javacsript free.</p>
    </header>
    <main>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, tempora voluptatum porro. Harum odio, sapiente dicta, eum quidem porro atque quisquam impedit officia ullam minus, laudantium vel eaque doloribus rem.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, tempora voluptatum porro. Harum odio, sapiente dicta, eum quidem porro atque quisquam impedit officia ullam minus, laudantium vel eaque doloribus rem.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Всмысле чтобы была img src?

Comment: прописать не в css а в html